# Bluetooth issues on note 2 when paired to speaker

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-2, bluetooth-audio

**Problem :** After pairing Galaxy note 2 (Android 4.4.2) with my Bluetooth speaker ( Jbl flip 2) i get a lot of fluctuation in sound while playing any song.

Even when i slightly move the device or the speaker, then i notice following changes:

- Sound fluctuation
- pauses while playing
- finally speaker gets disconnected.

The problem is only noticeable when i pair it with Galaxy note 2. My Bluetooth speaker doesn't have any problem when pairing with other devices.

**What have i tried:**

1. I have tried to disconnect and reconnect the Bluetooth device.
2. Restarted my device and then again paired.
3. I have even formatted my device.

Please help me to fix this error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say slightly move, how much do you mean exactly? There's [a range Bluetooth devices work in](http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/Basics.aspx). Are you sure you're not moving out of range?

If that's not the issue, try updating your phone, or installing a custom ROM. Another possibility is that there is a problem with your Bluetooth driver, but an upgrade in your phone might solve it. Note at this point it's like threading a needle in the dark and the issue seems rare, so it might not actually solve the problem.

Comment: No, the problem is not in range. Even if i keep those devices tied together, and move my phone then i get that same fluctuation.

Comment: Try updating your firmware or updating your phone , installing a custom rom might also solve the problem but this is all threading a needle in the dark.

Comment: I think this is the only solution left for me, i will give it a try.